# What are some exaples of Extranjerismos no adaptados and Heterónimos?

Tags: ortografía, extranjerismos, polisemia

[*Extranjerismos no adaptados*](https://www.rae.es/espanol-al-dia/los-extranjerismos-y-latinismos-crudos-no-adaptados-deben-escribirse-en-cursiva) refers to loanwords from other languages that keep their original spelling and pronunciation e.g. ["el bagel"](http://cervantesobservatorio.fas.harvard.edu/sites/default/files/diccionario_anglicismos.pdf), which pronounces the "g" as such, even though it is followed by an "e".

[Heteronyms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heteronym_(linguistics)) are words that is spelt the same, but have a different pronunciation and meaning. An example in English is "gill":

- "gill" /ɡɪl/ - [a respiratory organ in aquatic animals](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/gill?s=t), and
- "gill" /dʒɪl/ - [a unit of liquid measure](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/gill?s=t)

So, heteronyms (*heterónimos*) would occur if a word under "extranjerismos no adaptados" has the same spelling as a native Spanish word. So, I just wanted to know some examples of these words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common example of "extranjerismo no adaptado" is `pizza`, pronounced `pitsa`. Less common are such as `garage`, `iceberg`, `élite`, which, depending on the region, can be pronounced more or less like the original word (Argentina), or literally read as if they were Spanish words (Spain).

Some very slight heteronyms are created by the new graphical stress rules, which don't distinguish between diphthongs and hiatuses. For example, `pie`. `/'pje/`: foot, `/pi'e/`: I tweeted or chirped.

Given the prevalence of English in commerce, there are some "extranjerismos" which share their spelling with a native word, but they aren't generally used in common speech.

One example is "SALE". `/sejl/` - sale, `/'sale/` - he/she/it goes out.

I'll add some more if I think of them.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there are very few, since most unadapted loanwords with plausible Spanish pronunciations (given their spelling) tend to be<sup>1</sup> adapted as is e.g. English [*rail*](https://dle.rae.es/ra%C3%ADl).

One example I was able to find:

| Palabra | Heterónimo nativo | Extranjerismo no adaptado |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [adagio](https://dle.rae.es/adagio) | /aˈdaxjo/ | /aˈdaʤo/ (Italian) |

---

1. [Adaptación y uso de los extranjerismos en la 23.ª edición del *Diccionario de la lengua española*](https://revistas.ucm.es/index.php/CLAC/article/download/63284/4564456549280/0)